# Importing ArcGIS colour scheme into QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, symbology, color-ramp

I've just imported a soil map of Ireland into QGIS.  However, all soil associations are displaying in one colour.  The associated zip file includes a 'layer file' containing the colour scheme for the soil associations in ESRI ArcGIS format - please can someone tell me if and how I might import this into QGIS?

Comment: Ah, thank you both - I've just moved over to QGIS and had not come across SLD files before.  Sorry for duplicating, and thanks for pointing me in the right direction!